# vb.net reading data from csv error in date column

Tags: vb.net

I am reading data from a CSV file into a Sql table. Problem is some dates in a date column in the CSV would be empty. I am using the following code to convert the empty cells to NULL values. However I get the following error :Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store  in ANALISEDATUM Column.  Expected type is DateTime

My code is :

```
     Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
        Dim data As String() = parser.ReadFields()
        For i As Integer = 0 To data.Length - 1

            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data(i))) Then
                data(i) = DBNull.Value.ToString
            End If
        Next
        datatabel.Rows.Add(data)
```

The error occurs at the last line.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think, seems the format of the date adding to the table is wrong, please make sure the format of the table date column and csv file date value are same.
Ex: Table date format might be : mm/dd/yyyy
csv file date value format might be : dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: My CSV is dd/mm/yy. How do I set the datatable format? I have datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ANALISEDATUM", GetType(Date)))